# Best way to extract all _id from mongodb collection

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, pymongo

What is best way to extract all _id from mongodb collection? I am using pymongo to work with mongodb. Following code:

```
for item in db.some_collection.find({}, {'_id': 1}):
    # do something
```

takes some time to iterate over all collection.  I need only _id values and they all should fit in memory. Why does this code not complete immediately?

Answer (score 7):

Use [`distinct`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct):

```
some_collection.distinct('_id')
```

---

```
In [5]: c = pymongo.connection.Connection('127.0.0.1')

In [6]: c['test']['test'].insert({'a': 2})
Out[6]: ObjectId('5159c8e9d286da0efccb7b70')

In [7]: c['test']['test'].insert({'a': 3})
Out[7]: ObjectId('5159c8ecd286da0efccb7b71')

In [8]: c['test']['test'].insert({'a': 5})
Out[8]: ObjectId('5159c8edd286da0efccb7b72')

In [9]: c['test']['test'].distinct('_id')
Out[9]:
[ObjectId('5159c8e9d286da0efccb7b70'),
 ObjectId('5159c8ecd286da0efccb7b71'),
 ObjectId('5159c8edd286da0efccb7b72')]
```

Comment: Thank you. It works really fast:


    import pymongo
    import time

    db = pymongo.Connection()['moviedb']

    start = time.time()
    movie_ids = db.kp_movie.distinct('_id')
    print len(movie_ids)
    print 'Distinct: %.3f' % (time.time() - start)

    start = time.time()
    movie_ids = []
    for movie in db.kp_movie.find({}, {'_id': 1}):
        movie_ids.append(movie['_id'])
    print len(movie_ids)
    print 'Find: %.3f' % (time.time() - start)

result:

    $ python test.py 
    451943
    Distinct: 1.256
    451943
    Find: 29.083

Sorry, I don't know why all lines are merged.